# Posting html form data to php and accessing that through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to post some data to an html form, then that form sends the data to php, and finally javascript takes the data from that php.

This is my html form:

```
<form action="search.php" method='POST'>
    <input id="movie_name" name="movie_name" type="text">
    <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data">
</form>
```

This is my php file which is called search.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['movie_name']))
    {
    $movie_name = $_POST['movie_name'];
    echo '<script>', 'hello();', 'var movie = '$movie_name';', '</script>';
    }    
?>
```

Finally my js script which is in the same file as the php one:

```
function hello(){
    console.log('<?php echo $movie_name?;>');
}
```

What happens when I load this is that my html redirects ok and then for some in search.php nothing happens, the page goes white and the only thing the console says is "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly you want is not clear. But i suggest you to use jQuery ajax like this:

```
 <input id="movie_name" name="movie_name" type="text">
 <input id="myBtn" name="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit Data">

 $('#myBtn').click(function(e){
 var movie_name = $('#movie_name').val();
      $.ajax({
               url: "search.php",
               type: "POST",
               data: {
                   'movie_name': movie_name
               },
               beforeSend : function() {
               },
               success : function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
               },
               error : function()
               {                                                
               },
               complete : function() {
               }
          });               
   });
```

in your search.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['movie_name']))
    {
        $movie_name = $_POST['movie_name'];
        echo $movie_name;
    }    
?>
```

This is better way from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['movie_name'])){
    $movie_name = $_POST['movie_name'];
  }  
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function hello(){
    console.log('<?php echo $movie_name; ?>');
  }
</script>

<?php
  echo '<script> alert("'.$movie_name.'"); hello(); </script>';
?>
```

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't work, when I call the function hello, everything in the page goes blank and the error message is : "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html..."